# Development WCF server configuration

Tags: wcf, testing

I am trying to come up with a way to accomplish something but haven't been able to find what I am looking for yet.

- 4 Developers
- 1 Development webserver
- 1 Development WCF server
- We each have our own website for testing/debugging on the one server using IIS6. We each have our own port number that distinguishes what site we are connecting to.
- When our websites make a request for the WCF server the hosts file on our dev webserver points it at our dev WCF server. Likewise, the production webserver's hosts file points it at our production WCF server. This way we never have to worry about changing the Address of our service references in Visual Studio.
- Recently we have a need for multiple developers to be working on multiple branches of the WCF code at the same time. Currently we have to take turns using the WCF server.
- We want the ability to have our individual websites on the dev webserver point at individual WCF websites on our dev WCF server.
- I have tried several ways I thought of but they all require us to update the Address in the service reference in Visual Studio. (currently if we update/add a service call we point our local machine's host file at the dev site after the new WCF code has been deployed to it.)

Does anyone have any idea, or a direction of where I can find common configurations for this type of thing? I have to assume that Microsoft has a *best practices* setup for multiple developers with multiple dev environments for websites and WCF sites.

Requirements of the setup:

- We only get a single webserver for website testing.
- We only get a single webserver for WCF testing.
- We need a solution that doesn't require us to update the Address in the service reference in Visual Studio when developing on the WCF code.

If worse comes to worse we may have to think about changing the requirements.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Any thought to running things locally and then used a shared dev server for integrating the code base?  I have done exactly what you are talking about with larger dev teams and that worked out pretty well.  Am I missing someting?

Comment: The code base won't run locally because of dependencies on servers registries. It is against company policy to put this info on our local machines. I use the remote debugger on the server when I need to debug code.

Comment: I have always just done local dev and testing from a local instance (using IIS Express) right from VisualStudio by hard-coding a port number in the project settings, then setting the web services to use localhost and that hard coded port number. Is there some limitation where you have to deploy it to a central server for individual testing?

Comment: Virtualization and local wcf service hosting seems to be keys here

Comment: "The code base won't run locally because of dependencies on servers registries." - Ouch. Is this something you can mock out or use test data for? If you are just doing dev and testing, even integration testing, you should be able to use a DI framework to inject some test rigged up data instead of the real ones that you can't copy locally. Otherwise you are asking how to host >1 WCF service at the same URL at the same port on the same machine, which isn't really possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the address of the service in configuration file for each deployment. You don't need to change the address of service reference until the service has changed in the way that would produce different client proxy code.

Comment: Are you talking about the address of the service reference when you click on Configure? If so we each would need our own, and we are trying to keep things clean in source control. IE, we don't want to  have to modify the address each time we work on it, and then remember to not commit it back to source control.